# script not found even though it's in PATH

Tags: linux, terminal, path

Have a look at this terminal output...

```
bjorn@jungleland:~$ cd bin
bjorn@jungleland:~/bin$ ./first.sh 
Hello World
bjorn@jungleland:~/bin$ cd ..
bjorn@jungleland:~$ pwd
/home/bjorn
bjorn@jungleland:~$ echo $PATH
/home/bjorn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/bjorn/bin
bjorn@jungleland:~$ ./first.sh
bash: ./first.sh: No such file or directory
bjorn@jungleland:~$
```

How come first.sh isn't found when I'm in my home directory?
I have tried logging out and in again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are specifically running `./first.sh`, i.e. a script called "first.sh" that is in the **current directory** (`./`). Whether it is in the $PATH or not is irrelevant. If you give a full path, as you are doing, the system will look for the executable at the path given. Compare the commands below:

```
/bin/ls      <-- works
ls           <-- works
../../bin/ls <-- works if you are in $HOME
./ls         <-- fails unless you are in /bin
```

What you want to run is `first.sh` instead of `./first.sh`.

Comment: Oh so **that's** what the ./ is for! That explains alot. I always figured it was some kind of way to tell bash I was trying to run a script, as opposed to invoking a native command. Thank you!